# How to load image using iimage-mode when I first open a markdown file?

Tags: hooks, images, markdown

I have a file which embeds an image

```
![](file://tmp.jpg)
```

I have added iimage mode to the markdown mode hook and even added recenter  to it

```
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'iimage-mode)
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'iimage-recenter)
```

However when I open the file the image is not loaded automatically. I have to manually run the `iimage-recenter` command inside the buffer before the image is actually loaded.  in the buffer. Any suggestions how I can specify to run `iimage-recenter` after a particular file is loaded. I am guessing I'll have to edit some hook (maybe after-insert-file-functions?), but not sure which one.

Comment: `iimage-mode` is incompatible with `markdown-mode`. `iimage-mode` just uses the `display` property to display paths as images while `markdown-mode` has the `display` property in its value for the variable `font-lock-extra-managed-props`. So `font-lock` removes the `display` properties set by `iimage-mode` immediately when it (re)fontifies (parts of) the buffer. Even if you have a fast hack to temporarily display images with iimage those images will be removed by `font-lock` when you edit text near the image or if the image is in a part of the buffer that is not yet rendered by font-lock.

Comment: Note that `markdown-mode` has a command `markdown-toggle-inline-images` that does almost what you want. The style of the link is a bit different. The command expects the file name without url schema, i.e., `![](tmp.jpg)`. If you adapt to that convention you can just add `'markdown-toggle-inline-images` to `markdown-mode-hook`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.